# Connecting to Presto via Windows command prompt?

Tags: command-prompt, presto

I am not sure if it is even a legit question but here is the background.

The company database is setup in Presto and I would need to connect to Presto to run some queries. When I asked the development team and I was given the following [link](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html) as a reference. I barely know anything about command line so I decide to give it a shot anyway. I use a Windows 10 PC.

I followed the instructions on the link, access the Presto CLI from Windows' command prompt and I am stuck at the stage of connecting to the Presto server. The command that I used to connect is the following, where `<abc>` is the placeholder for my details:

`./presto-cli --server <company_database> --catalog hive --schema <my_schema> --user <my_username> --<my_password>`

However, the above command does not connect my PC to the database. May I know what could possibly go wrong?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what happens when you run the command?  Do you get an exception? Does it hang?  Have you tried getting a stack trace (IIRC CTRL+Break)?

Comment: @Dain The output shows "->”. Seems that it is asking me to input more commands.

Comment: That is strange.  The CLI will normally prompt with "hive:company_database>".  Maybe the "->" is from the shell due to an unclosed quote in the command?

Comment: @DainSundstrom Eventually I was able to connect to the database using Metabase by following all the instructions on the website.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with below command on windows system.
**`java -jar presto-cli-0.230-executable.jar --server <host:port> --catalog <catalog_name> --schema <schema_name> --user <user_name> --<password>`**

Answer (score 0):

When I asked this question, the plan was to come out of a way to send SQL queries to the Presto database. I discovered [Metabase](http://www.metabase.com) and have successfully using it  to connect my PC to the company database.